# How to calculate percent dynamically?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$65$ is $100 \%$ and $55$ is $0 \%$. How can I calculate the percentage of all other numbers, , starting from 55 to 65?

Comment: Google search "equation of a line given two points."

Comment: That, or if you don't care about learning how to do it yourself... just type it into [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=line+from+%2855%2C0%29+to+%2865%2C100%29).

Comment: Can you clearly write your question ??

Comment: So the distance bewteen $55$ to $65$ represents $100\%$.  As $55$ to $65$ is a total of $10$, $10$ units represent $100\%$ so each unit represents $10\%$.  The numbers starts at $55$ so you have to subtract $55$ to get to zero.  So the if you number is $N$ that represents $(N-55)\times 10$ percent.

Comment: I don't take it positively giving down-vote to this question. This question may help the OP

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR  I don't take it positively that you answered this problem-statement question

Comment: @amWhy, If you see already $3$ answers are given. That is not matter, this easy question may help the OP.

Comment: Lots of people may answer easy homework problems, @M.A.SARKAR, because they gain the answerer easily earned rep. But that doesn't the question appropriate, nor the answerers decisions to answer it appropriate.

Comment: @amWhy, It maybe easy to someone but the same may be new to someone. Infact, someone may not have mathematical background although have right to get the help from this forum.

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR  I have no problem with level of difficulty, but both you and the asker need to read, carefully, [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|126.4067), and you need to stop supporting poorly asked questions on this site.  At the very least, it justifies the downvotes on this question.

Comment: @amWhy, well,I should stop here.I believe in helping no matter what is the level of the  question unless otherwise.If you have much problem, you can draw attention of the #moderator. Thanks

Comment: Rather than giving a full proper answer which explains the general process to solving all problems of this type that the OP will ignore anyways, giving them a tool like wolframalpha that you can just type in the question and it answer immediately with no need to bother other humans is superior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider the points $(65,100)$ and $(55,0)$,then the line joining them is $$ \frac{y-0}{x-55}=\frac{100-0}{65-55}.$$ This gives us $$ y=10(x-55).$$ So the percentage of any number $x$ in $55<x<65$ is given by $$y=10(x-55) \% .$$ For example,if you take $x=60$,then $y=10(60-55) \%=50 \%$.

Comment: Great answer, it helped me a lot. Thank you!

Comment: @RezaSaadati, You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If $ x$ is the value between $55$ and $65$, and assuming a linear dependence, the percentage $p$ is $$p=\frac{x-55}{65-55}\times 100\%$$

Comment: .... times 100.....

Comment: @fleablood thanks

Answer (score 0):

So the distance bewteen $55$ to $65$ represents $100\%$.  As $55$ to $65$ is a total of $10$ units, $10$ units represent $100\%$. So each unit above $55$ represents $10\%$.

So if you start with $N$ that is $N -55$ units above $55$ and represents $(N-55)\times 10$ percent.